# Chutzpah & TypeScript

Tags: typescript, chutzpah

I'm using `typescript 9.1.1` as the company I work for (a bank) hasn't approved the latest compiler.  I know `chutzpah` automatically compiles your type script files for you but does anyone know how you configure what compiler it uses?

Answer (score 1):

Since the option to specify compiler version is not there jet as Matthew Manela noted, maybe it will be an option switch Chutzpah to External compilation mode. See [compile settings](https://github.com/mmanela/chutzpah/wiki/Compile-Setting) page on github for details. Here is the minimal setup you will need:

```
"Compile": {
    "Mode": "External",
    "Extensions": [ ".ts" ],
    "ExtensionsWithNoOutput": [ ".d.ts" ],
    "SourceDirectory": "{path}",
    "OutDirectory": "{path}"
},
```

Answer (score 0):

So I've found that chutzpah embeds the latest version of the typescript compiler into the extension. There is currently a work item raised to make this configurable.

https://chutzpah.codeplex.com/workitem/183

Answer (score 0):

Chutzpah does embed TypeScript and its newest version is using 0.9.5 but if you want to you the previous release which used 0.9.1 you can get the console runner from nuget and the previous vsix version from [here](https://skydrive.live.com/#cid=D08E5C6BF97C4C7B&id=D08E5C6BF97C4C7B!22241)

I do plan on making it configurable but that won't come soon.